# Counting paths in a recursive call

Tags: python, recursion, counter

The problem I'm working on is this, from Cracking the Coding Interview:

"A child is running up a staircase with n steps, and can hop either 1 step, 2 steps,
or 3 steps at a time. Implement a method to count how many possible ways the
child can run up the stairs."

Coming from C++ I know that a counter can be passed as reference, but in python you can't. I am also trying to track the step sequence that results in a success. I'm writing my code like this:

```
def __calculatePaths(currPathLength, paths, currSeries):
  if currPathLength == 0:
    print "successful series is", currSeries
    return 1
  elif currPathLength < 0: return 0

  for i in range(1, 4):
    newSeries = list(currSeries)  # make new series to track steps
    newSeries.append(i)
    paths += __calculatePaths(currPathLength - i, paths, newSeries)
  return paths

def calculatePaths(pathLength):
  paths = __calculatePaths(pathLength, 0, [])
  return paths

if __name__ == '__main__':
    calculatePaths(3)
```

The output for this call is:

```
successful series is [1, 1, 1]
successful series is [1, 2]
successful series is [2, 1]
successful series is [3]
6
```

I'm confused because my program gets the correct path sequences, but the wrong number of paths. How should I be incrementing my paths? I know how to do this without a global variable, but I can't figure it out without using one. Thank you!

Comment: Can you use maths, or does it have to be brute force?

Comment: A brute force solution would be the most generalizable to other recursive problems (since I'm having trouble understanding the general principle of using a counter in recursive problems here)

Comment: In Python, if you make the counter a container (like a list) and pass it as an argument, you're effectively passing it by reference. Also, if you're going to write Python code, I _strongly_ suggest you follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function __calculatePaths, you have to set paths = 0, before the for loop. Otherwise it is add the values to the global instance of paths and that's why you are getting wrong answer.

```
def __calculatePaths(currPathLength, paths, currSeries):
  if currPathLength == 0:
    print "successful series is", currSeries
    return 1
  elif currPathLength < 0: return 0
  paths = 0
  for i in range(1, 4):
    newSeries = list(currSeries)  # make new series to track steps
    newSeries.append(i)
    paths += __calculatePaths(currPathLength - i, paths, newSeries)
  return paths

def calculatePaths(pathLength):
  paths = __calculatePaths(pathLength, 0, [])
  return paths

if __name__ == '__main__':
    calculatePaths(3)
```

You can get the number of ways in much efficient manner. By using Dynamic Programming in O(N). And even more efficiently using matrix exponentiation O(logN).

Comment: What do you mean the global instance of paths? Isn't a copy of paths made in each recursive call when it is passed in?

Comment: Since, you are not resetting the value of `paths` to 0, it adds the value returned from the recursive function call to the same `paths` variable which was used earlier. So,since you coming from C++ background, you can think it as `paths` variable being treated as a global variable. And every time, any value is added to `paths` , the value is added to that global `paths` variable

Answer (score 1):

Most important, realize that you don't have to determine those sequences: you need only to count them.  For instance, there's only one way to finish from step N-1: hop 1 step.  From N-2, there are two ways: hop both steps at once, or hop 1 step and finish from there.  Our "ways to finish" list now looks like this, working backwards:

```
way = [1, 2, ...]
```

Now, watch what happens with step N-3.  We finally have 3 choices:

1. Hop 1 step and have 2 ways to finish
2. Hop 2 steps and have 1 way to finish
3. Hop 3 steps and be done.

That's a total of 2+1+1, or 4 ways to finish.

That initializes our algorithm.  Now for the recurrence relationship.  The initial list looks like this:

```
way = [1, 2, 4, ...]
```

From here on, we can't make a single hop to the top.  Instead, we have to depend on the three steps above us.  Our choices from step N-J are:

1. Hop 1 step  and have **way[J-1]** ways to finish
2. Hop 2 steps and have **way[J-2]** ways to finish
3. Hop 3 steps and have **way[J-3]** ways to finish

Thus, for all j >= 3:

```
way[j] = way[j-1] + way[j-2] + way[j-3]
```

This gives you the solution in **O(N)** time.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the most efficient way to do it computing-wise using your solution:

```
from collections import deque


def calculate_paths(length):
    count = 0  # Global count

    def calcuate(remaining_length):
        # 0 means success
        # 1 means only 1 option is available (hop 1)
        if remaining_length < 2:
            nonlocal count  # Refer to outer count
            count += 1
            return

        # Calculates, removing the length already passed.
        # For 1...4 or remaining_length+1 if it's less than 4.
        # deque(, maxlen=0) is the fastest way of consuming an iterator
        # without also keeping it's data. This is the most efficient both
        # memory-wise and clock-wise
        deque((calcuate(remaining_length-i)
              for i in range(1, min(4, remaining_length+1))), maxlen=0)

    calcuate(length)
    return count

>>> calculate_paths(2)
2
>>> calculate_paths(3)
4
>>> calculate_paths(4)
7
```

As you can see, there is no need to keep the path as only the remaining length matters.

---

@Prune's answer has better algorithm. Here it is implemented:

```
def calculate_paths(length):
    results = deque((1, 2, 4), maxlen=3)
    if length <= 3:
        return results[length-1]

    for i in range(3, length):
        results.append(sum(results))

    return results.pop()
```

Eliminating recursion also causes less frames to be used, and doesn't stop with max recursion.